# "Incorrect syntax" and "Cannot be bound" when adding alias to Grouping Sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a common column (Name0) that I need to select from one of my tables. So, I alias it out, but then it starts throwing errors. The two columns I try to select show they could not be bound, followed by my aggregate having syntax errors. Finally, the grouping by set alias' show incorrect syntax. I am at a loss.

```
Select I.ARPDisplayName0,
      SR.name0 = coalesce(SR.name0,concat('Total ',sum(1)))
 
 From  v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE I
 inner join  v_R_System SR on SR.resourceID = I.ResourceID
 inner join  v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS on OS.ResourceID = I.ResourceID

 WHERE
    ARPDisplayName0 = 'Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro' or 
    ARPDisplayName0 = 'Bomgar' or
    Caption0 = 'Microsoft Windows 7 Professional'

 Group By Grouping Sets ( 
                        (I.ARPDisplayName0,SR.name0),
                        (I.ARPDisplayName0),
                        (OS.Caption0,SR.Name0),
                        (OS.Caption0)
                        ()
                        );
```

Specific errors:

> Incorrect Syntax expecting (or Select" in coalesce(SR.name0,concat('Total ',sum(1))) and in the grouping sets alias.

The other error is:

> the Multipart Identifier could not be bound in the SELECT statement "I.ARPDisplayName0" and "SR.name0"

Comment: And thiose errors are..?

Comment: @Larnu The errors are "Incorrect Syntax expecting ( or Select" in "= coalesce(SR.name0,concat('Total ',sum(1)))" and in the grouping sets alias. The other error is the Multipart Identifier could not be bound in the SELECT statement "I.ARPDisplayName0" and "SR.name0"

Comment: Just curious if you alias your 2nd column as `col2` or something other than `SR.name0` what happens?  My theory is the SQL order of operations executes teh group by before the select so the value for SR.Name0 hasn't been determined when you're trying to group by it since you appear to be resetting it in the select.

Comment: @xQbert Nothing changes. Still getting "Could not be bound" in the SELECT ```SR.name0```

Comment: Suggest you include the schema of the tables or a *Fiddle* to reproduce the error.

Comment: `SR.name0` is not a valid alias for a column expression. You have an expression and the name you give it must be a regular identifier or be enclosed with the appropriate delimiters.

Comment: @SMor yes of course it should be just *name0* or *[SR.name0]*

Comment: @Smor @Stu Yes, that did resolve most of the errors! Only one is left '''[I.ARPDisplayName0],``` is showing "Invalid Column Name" now

Comment: Should `[I.ARPDisplayName0]` not be `I.ARPDisplayName0`, @My9to5 ?

Comment: @Larnu that did it! I don't understand, but Ill try to poke around for the reasons.

Comment: `[I.ARPDisplayName0]` refers to an unqualified column called "`I.ARPDisplayName0`" @My9to5 . `I.ARPDisplayName0` on the other hand references the column `ARPDisplayName0` in the object aliased as `I`. Brackets (`[]`) are delimit identifiers in T-SQL; they do the same thing as the ANSI delimit identifiers, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: you don't include aliases within square brackets, only the name of the actual column; `[]` aren't necessary at all unless the column name is a reserved word eg `[date]` or includes certain characters or spaces eg `[silly-column-name]`

Comment: @stu someone needs to provide an answer to this and get it accepted so it can be closed :P

Comment: @xQbert Ok as nobody else has I'll offer something!

Answer (score 1):

The issues arise from just from a simple misunderstanding of how to use alias.

When providing the name of an alias, you can choose to use either an `=` assignment or the (optional) keyword `as` - it's really personal preference which you use but I prefer the latter option and keep `=` for actually assigning values to local variables.

The line `SR.name0 = coalesce(SR.name0,concat('Total ',sum(1)))` is causing an error since SQL Server interprets the `SR.` as an alias reference itself which can't be used in this context - the intended name is just "name0"; constructing it as  `coalesce(SR.name0,concat('Total ',sum(1))) as name0` would make the intent clearer.

Likewise, when using brackets `[]` around object names, the alias dot-notation is not included, so `[I.ARPDisplayName0]` is just `I.[ARPDisplayName0]`; in this case the brackets are completely optional as they are only *required* if there is a clash with a reserved word eg `[date]` or the use of certain characters such as a space `[my column name]`. Again it's personal preference but I prefer to only use them where necessary to remove "noise" and improve readability.